# Move axis x from bottom to top in c3 js

Tags: c3.js

I am working on a project and use c3 js library (don't use d3 js)
And now I'm having a problem, that is when using c3 js, the x-axis of the graph will default to the bottom, but the design they want it to be above, so how do I handle it?
Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks every body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you set the axis min and Max to limit the displayed area? https://c3js.org/reference.html#api-axis-min

```
chart.axis.min({
  x: -10,
  y: 1000,
  y2: 100
});
chart.axis.max({
  x: 100,
  y: 1000,
  y2: 10000
});
```

Comment: tried and did not work :(
I mean this: https://imgur.com/Q1BThun

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a feature of c3js to change the origin/intersect. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202593/change-origin-from-zero-to-one-in-c3-graph

Comment: Let me ask more, the number of lines from axis 0 to the smallest number is given by the library itself, so is there a way to set the number of lines (eg for example, the picture is 5 lines, each line corresponds to 20, I want only 4, each line corresponds to 25) what should I do?

Comment: I think the answer to that might be demonstrated here: https://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_count.html . The property is `chart.axis.x.tick.count` a qty of ticks, or `chart.axis.x.tick.values`, an array of tick values (`y` instead of `x` for the y-axis). That is, if the library derives lines from the c3 tick values.